# Disconnected metric space proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $(A, d)$ be a metric space. Show that if $A$ is connected then $A$ is not countable.

Note about the definition of countable: A set $X$ is countable if it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$.

My attempt:

I use a contrapositive argument:

Assume instead that $A$ is a countable set. We need to show that $A$ is disconnected/not connected.

Take $a \in A$. The set $E := \{d(a, b): b \in E\}$ is countable. So there exists $a_n \rightarrow 0$ where $a_n \notin E$. The ball of radius $a_n$ about $a$, denoted $B(a, a_n)$, is empty so $B(a, a_n)$ is both open and closed. Therefore $a$ the largest set containing itself. We may conclude that $A$ is totally disconnected.

Does totally disconnected imply disconnected? If so, is this proof correct? If not, what would a correct proof look like? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is basically correct, but you don’t need a sequence, and do need to make sure that your ball doesn’t include the whole space. Pick a point $b\in A\setminus\{a\}$, and let $r=d(a,b)$. Then the interval $(0,r)$ in $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, while the set $E=\{d(a,x):x\in A\}$ is only countable, so there is an $s\in(0,r)\setminus E$. Then $B(a,s)$ is clopen, $a\in B(a,s)$, and $b\in A\setminus B(a,s)$, so $A$ is not connected: $B(a,s)$ and $A\setminus B(a,s)$ are disjoint non-empty open subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$.

And you can use that last argument in general to show that a totally disconnected space is not connected.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Two things: Why is the interval $(0, r)$ uncountable in $\mathbb{R}$? Also, I understand the general intuition but I struggle to put the proof down formally.

Comment: @Kraftsman: If $u<v$, there is a bijection between $(u,v)$ and $\Bbb R$. For instance, you can map $\Bbb R$ to $\left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right)$ with the $\arctan$ function and then use a function of the form $f(x)=ax+b$ to map $\left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right)$ bijectively onto $(u,v)$.

Comment: Sorry... I just realized something: How would I show that the set $E$ is countable? I know I could find a bijection but is there a simpler way?

Comment: @SupremePickle: That’s about as simple as it gets: $A$ is countable, and the map from $A$ to $E$ that takes $x$ to $d(a,x)$ is a surjection, so $E$ is necessarily countable.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Also, I noticed your answer uses $X$ as opposed to $A$ at some points. Feel free to edit it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SupremePickle: Thanks for catching that: I tend to use $X$ and $Y$ for spaces automatically.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Your argument may be not true. e.g. $E = \{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$, if you choose $x=0$, then you cannot find a number less than all distances.

Comment: @OneLamp: Nothing in my argument requires finding such a number. If $A=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ and $a=0$, I can take $s=\frac23$, for instance, getting the separation into the clopen sets $$B\left(0,\frac23\right)=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{1\}\right\}$$ and $$A\setminus B\left(0,\frac23\right)=\{1\}\,.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're right. It's my misunderstanding. Thanks.

Comment: @OneLamp: You’re welcome.